# Java: Using server to create P2P between two clients

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server, p2p

I am experimenting with a file transfer program in Java and I wanted to create a server that would handle creating P2P connection between two clients.

Don't know how that should work, exchanging sockets? I don't want to exchange IP address... Seen some questions similar (ev. [Connecting two clients via server java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271793/connecting-two-clients-via-server-java)) but I have no idea how to achieve that.
Thanks for your time

Comment: What's wrong with sending the IP to one client, and tell the other client to listen for a connection?  What the linked question suggests, is to use the server as a bridge between the two clients (with all data being sent through the server, not directly to the other client)

Comment: Because sending IPs would require forwarding ports, wouldn't it? (correct me if im wrong)
Also I don't want to do the whole transmission through server because it make the servers bandwidth a limiting factor

Comment: As far as I know, you need to either deal with the firewalls or be stuck with the server in the middle.  I haven't come across a method that would redirect the open ports to eachother _(which I really want, for my projects)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [nat traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) techniques. There is no single solution because there are many different network setups. Most p2p software employs a combination of different solutions, such as using IPv6 where available, negotiating with home routers and operating system firewalls or NAT hole punching. Servers can assist in the last point.

Comment: Thanks, I've started looking into that. Probably will try to settle on hole punching, what pains me is from what I've read it won't be always effective... Well, will post here if I develop some working piece of code. Thank you